# C# String processing a non-delimited string to list

Tags: c#, string

Here is an example of the string in question:

```
[952,M] [782,M] [782] {2[373,M]} [1470] [352] [235] [234] {3[610]}{3[380]} [128] [127]
```

I have added the spaces but it really does not help the breakdown. What I want to do is take each "field" in square brackets and add it to a string list. The next issue which I can handle is some fields also have a comma separated portion that I can split after the fact. The real problem lies in the Curly braces. For instance `{2[373,M]}` The number outside the square brackets is a repetition of the square brackets.

For the life of me I can not figure out a way where I can consistently split the line into a string list.

Quasi code follows:

```
for(i = 0 to string.length)
{
    if string.substring(i,1) = "]"
        int start1 = i
    elseif string.substring(i,1)="["
        int start1 = i
    elseif string.substring(i,1) = "{"
        int start2 = i
    elseif string.substring(i,1) = "}"
        int end2 = i
}
```

I thought about using the code idea above to substring out each "field" but the curly braces also contain the square brackets. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the lack of a space in `{3[610]}{3[380]}` a typo or something that you can expect in your input?

Comment: 1) What do you *want* `{2[373,M]}` to turn into? Two strings of `373,M`? 2) `string.substring(i,1) == "]"` is ridiculous. Just do `string[i] == ']'`.

Comment: Asad Saeeduddin That is a mistake in my string manipulation.

Comment: itsme86 That is not ridiculous I am looking for a single character not the rest of the string. I need each square bracket separate from the whole string so I can add it to a string list. The curly braces tell me to add the square bracket to the list X times. In the case you provided it should be added twice.

Comment: Is there a way you can talk to the provider of this data that they may format it in a manner that's more easily parsable (e.g., CSV, JSON, XML)? Were I a regex expert, I'm sure I could come up with a simple and elegant solution.

Comment: @jhdeval It *is* ridiculous. `string[i]` gives you a single character from the string. `string.substring(i,1)` creates a *new* string needlessly that's length 1, containing the character at `i`.

Comment: @jhdeval Sorry, but it still isn't exactly clear. After your edit, there still isn't a space between `{3[610]}` and `{3[380]}`. Is this expected or a typo?

Comment: Bob Kaufman No this is Legacy data no way for me to get it in any other way. I have about 50 files like this so reformatting by hand is not really an option.

Comment: itsme86 Maybe we are confused here. The code above is QUASI code it will not execute in any language. string is the string I want to parse. i is the loop integer and 1 is the length. No matter what the original problem exists the line needs to be parsed into 17 individual strings and added to a string list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = "[952,M] [782,M] [782] {2[373,M]} [1470] [352] [235] [234] {3[610]}{3[380]} [128] [127]";

var s2 = Regex.Replace(s, @"\{(\d+)(\[[^]]+\])\}", m => string.Concat( 
    Enumerable.Repeat(m.Groups[2].Value, int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value))));

var a = s2.Split("[] ".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// s2 = "[952,M] [782,M] [782] [373,M][373,M] [1470] [352] [235] [234] [610][610][610][380][380][380] [128] [127]"
// a = {"952,M","782,M","782","373,M","373,M","1470","352","235","234","610","610","610","380","380","380","128","127"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to split the characters surrounded by brackets, and when they have curly brackets repeat the content inside the specified number of times.

You can extract all the information you need with a regex, including the number needed to determine the number of times you need to repeat a bracket

```
var input = @"[952,M] [782,M] [782] {2[373,M]} 
              [1470] [352] [235] [234] {3[610]}{3[380]} [128] [127]";

var pattern = @"((:?\{(\d+)(.*?)\})|(:?\[.*?\]))";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

var ls = new List<string>();

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    // check if the item has curly brackets
    // The captures groups will be different if there were curly brackets

    // If there are brackets than the 4th capture group 
    // will have the value of the square brackets and it's content
    if( match.Groups[4].Success ) 
    {
        var value = match.Groups[4].Value;

        // The "Count" of the items will 
        // be in the third capture group
        var count = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            ls.Add(value);
        } 

    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise we know that square bracket input 
        // is in the first capture group
        ls.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

Here is a working fiddle of the solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4rQsDj

Here is the output :

```
[952,M]
[782,M]
[782]
[373,M]
[373,M]
[1470]
[352]
[235]
[234]
[610]
[610]
[610]
[380]
[380]
[380]
[128]
[127]
```

If you don't want the brackets can get rid of them by changing the regex pattern to `(:?(:?\{(\d+)\[(.*?)\]\})|(:?\[(.*?)\]))`, and `match.Groups[1].Value` to `match.Groups[6].Value`.

Here is the working solution without square brackets: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OQwStf

Comment: This seems like the best RegEx solution. I would be curious about the performance compared to my solution.

Comment: @JonathanWood not sure, know there are definitely issues with Regex performance in very large strings, maybe I will mess around with the fiddle see if I notice anything

Comment: At 1K lines of text, took about .08s, and at 500 took .03 seconds, so looks like linear growth, could probably improve the performance if the implementor compiled it

Answer (score 1):

The regex below will handle both situations:

```
(?:\{([^\[]+)){0,1}\[([^\]]+)\]\}{0,1}
```

For matches for your case without the curly braces, the first match will be empty. For the second case, the first match will contain your number of repeats. In both cases, the second match will contain the actual data. The link below shows a demo of this working:

[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com/3e9ar)

Note, however, that you will have to handle the repetition yourself in the code that makes use of the regex

Answer (score 1):

While you might be able to get by on RegEx, it may come up short if your needs grow too complex. So the code below shows the general approach I would take to accomplish this. It's a little quick and dirty but meets your requirements.

In addition, I have a [parsing helper class](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-text-parsing-helper-class) that would make this code easier to write and more robust.

```
string input = "[952,M] [782,M] [782] {2[373,M]} [1470] [352] [235] [234] {3[610]}{3[380]} [128] [127]";
int pos = 0;

void Main()
{
    while (pos < input.Length)
    {
        SkipWhitespace();
        if (pos < input.Length && input[pos] == '{')
            ParseBrace();
        else if (pos < input.Length && input[pos] == '[')
            ParseBracket();
    }
}

void SkipWhitespace()
{
    while (pos < input.Length && char.IsWhiteSpace(input[pos]))
        pos++;
}

void ParseBrace()
{
    Debug.Assert(pos < input.Length && input[pos] == '{');
    int pos2 = input.IndexOf('[', pos + 1);
    if (pos2 < 0)
        pos2 = input.Length;

    int count = int.Parse(input.Substring(pos + 1, pos2 - pos - 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        pos = pos2;
        ParseBracket();
    }

    pos2 = input.IndexOf('}', pos2 + 1);
    if (pos2 < 0)
        pos2 = input.Length;

    pos = pos2 + 1;
}

void ParseBracket()
{
    Debug.Assert(pos < input.Length && input[pos] == '[');
    int pos2 = input.IndexOf(']', pos + 1);
    if (pos2 < 0)
        pos2 = input.Length;
    Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(pos + 1, pos2 - pos - 1));
    pos = pos2 + 1;
}
```

Sample output:

```
952,M
782,M
782
373,M
373,M
1470
352
235
234
610
610
610
380
380
380
128
127
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex.

Edited: this manages problem with commas and repetititon:

```
        var regex3 = new Regex(@"(\B\[([a-zA-Z0-9\,]+)\])|(\{(\d+)\[([a-zA-Z0-9\,]+)\]\})");
        var stringOne = "[952,M] [782,M] [782] {2[373,M]} [1470] [352] [235] [234] {3[610]}{3[380]} [128] [127]";
        var matches = regex.Matches(stringOne);

        var listStrings = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            var repetitor = 1;
            string value = null;
            if (match.Groups[1].Value == string.Empty)
            {
                repetitor = int.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value);
                value = match.Groups[5].Value;
            }

            else
            {
                value = match.Groups[2].Value;
            }

            var values = value.Split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < repetitor; i++)
            {
                listStrings.AddRange(values);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is dead close the only problem with it is the curly braces. The number outside the square brackets indicates a repetition.  This {3[610]} would be added to the list 3 times.